# Getting admin template errors when changed default django user model

Tags: python, django

Hello I get this errors in log file when open http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/custom_users/customuser/
I create a custom user model to let my users login by email.
I googled some errors in this log and maybe it is known django bug, but I not find any solution.

```
Exception while resolving variable 'errors' in template 'admin/change_list.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'errors'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'errors'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [errors] in None
Exception while resolving variable 'show' in template 'admin/change_list.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'show'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 835, in _resolve_lookup
    if isinstance(current, BaseContext) and getattr(type(current), bit):
AttributeError: type object 'RequestContext' has no attribute 'show'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'show'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [show] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None, 'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: <function csrf.<locals>._get_val at 0x106d22ea0>>}]
(0.000) SELECT DISTINCT "custom_users_customuser"."email" FROM "custom_users_customuser" ORDER BY "custom_users_customuser"."email" ASC; args=()
Exception while resolving variable 'is_multipart' in template 'admin/change_list.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_multipart'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'is_multipart'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [is_multipart] in None
Exception while resolving variable 'non_field_errors' in template 'admin/change_list.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'non_field_errors'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'non_field_errors'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [non_field_errors] in None
Exception while resolving variable 'non_field_errors' in template 'admin/change_list.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'non_field_errors'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'non_field_errors'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/CODE/python/learn/django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [non_field_errors] in None
"GET /admin/custom_users/customuser/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6810
```

Custom user model from a lot of tutorials from the internet

```
from .managers import CustomUserManager


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # is_staff - can user login to admin dash
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    confirmed_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Returns the short name for the user."""
        return self.email
```

Logging settings

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'console': {
            # exact format is not important, this is the minimum information
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'debug.log'),
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your settings file, add "django.template" after "django" in "logger" like below:

```
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'django.template': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
```

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: Thanks, this help!